# Row_Number function inside Case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, row-number

Need some help with the below logic:

I have an orders table with the following data:

| Order_Id | created_date | Seller |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 01-01-2022 | xx |
| 001 | 02-01-2022 | xx |
| 001 | 03-01-2022 | xx |
| 001 | 04-01-2022 | yy |

I want the output as:

| Order_Id | created_date | Seller | Ordinal_number | Reverse_Ordinal_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 01-01-2022 | xx | 1 | 3 |
| 001 | 02-01-2022 | xx | 2 | 2 |
| 001 | 03-01-2022 | xx | 3 | 1 |
| 001 | 04-01-2022 | yy | 0 | 0 |

I've tried the below SQL:

```sql
Select Order_Id , Created_date ,     
Case when seller = 'xx' then row_number() over (partition by Order_Id Order by Created_Date ) else 0 end as Ordinal_number,        
Case when seller = 'xx' then row_number() over (partition by Order_Id Order by Created_Date Desc) else 0 end as Reverse_Ordinal_number            
from Orders
```

And I get the below output:

| Order_Id | created_date | Seller | Ordinal_number | Reverse_Ordinal_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 01-01-2022 | xx | 1 | 4 |
| 001 | 02-01-2022 | xx | 2 | 3 |
| 001 | 03-01-2022 | xx | 3 | 2 |
| 001 | 04-01-2022 | yy | 0 | 0 |

Works fine when i do order by in Ascending order but not when i do it in descending order

Comment: Can you explain this logic? Is 'xx` special and the other sellers should get a 0? something else?

Comment: To get a separate sequence if any for a seller `.. partition by seller, Order_Id..`

Comment: @Mureinik Yes , in this scenario im only considering orders sold by xx . Based on Reverse_Ordinal_number calculation , i have to set a flag for the latest product sold by him

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, the ordinal number should only be shown for the `xx` seller. However, the `row_number` call in your query doesn't take the seller into account. Add it to the `partition by` clause and you should be OK:

```sql
SELECT Order_Id, 
       Created_date,
       CASE Seller WHEN 'xx' 
                   THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Order_Id, Seller -- Here!
                                           ORDER BY Created_Date)
                    ELSE 0 END AS Ordinal_number,
       CASE Seller WHEN 'xx' 
                   THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Order_Id, Seller -- And here!
                                           ORDER BY Created_Date DESC)
                    ELSE 0 END AS Reverse_Ordinal_number,
FROM   Orders
```

Comment: Oh Myyy! 
How did I miss that.
Thank yu so much @Mureinik . Its working :)